# htaccess rule to rewrite %3F to ? and %3D to =

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, regex

I need to rewrite the URL of my site which contains %3F to ? and %3D to =

I have tried this rule:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myhostname    
  RewriteRule ^(.*)%3F(.+)%3D(.+)$ $1?$2=$3 [L,R=301]
```

And this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\%]+)\%3[Ff]\%3[dD]([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule \.*$ %1?%2=$3 [R=301,L]
```

But none worked.

Help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution. Adding following rules did it:

```
# If THE_REQUEST contains a URL-path with a percent-encoded "?" and/or a query string with one
# or more specific percent-encoded characters, and we're not already in the process of fixing
# it, then copy the client-requested URL-path-plus-query-string into the "MyURI" variable.
RewriteCond %{ENV:MyURI}>%{THE_REQUEST} ^>[A-Z]+\ /([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %1 ^([^?]*\?([^%]*(\%(25)*([^3].|.[^D]))*)*\%(25)*3D.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %1 ^([^?]*\?([^%]*(\%(25)*([^2].|.[^6]))*)*\%(25)*26.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %1 ^(([^%]*(\%(25)*([^3].|.[^F]))*)*\%(25)*3F.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^. - [NE,E=MyURI:%1]
#
# If any encoded question mark is present in the client-requested URI, and
# no unencoded question mark is present, replace the first encoded question
# mark, queue up a redirect, and then re-start mod_rewrite processing
RewriteCond %{ENV:MyURI} ^[^?]+$
RewriteCond %{ENV:MyURI} ^(([^%]*(\%(25)*([^3].|.[^F]))*)*)\%(25)*3F(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^. - [NE,E=MyURI:%1?%7,E=QRedir:Yes,N]
#
# If any encoded "=" sign follows the "?", replace it, queue
# up a redirect, and re-start mod_rewrite processing
RewriteCond %{ENV:MyURI} ^([^?]*\?([^%]*(\%(25)*([^3].|.[^D]))*)*)\%(25)*3D(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^. - [NE,E=MyURI:%1=%7,E=QRedir:Yes,N]
#
# If any encoded ampersand follows the "?", replace it, queue
# up a redirect, and then re-start mod_rewrite processing
RewriteCond %{ENV:MyURI} ^([^?]*\?([^%]*(\%(25)*([^2].|.[^6]))*)*)\%(25)*26(.*)$
RewriteRule ^. - [NE,E=MyURI:%1&%7,E=QRedir:Yes,N]
#
# If we get here, there are no more percent-encoded characters which can
# and should be replaced by the rules above, so do the external redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:QRedir} =Yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^. http://www.example.com/%{ENV:MyURI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Found it here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1193309.aspx?Need+help+transforming+3F+into+and+3D+into+

Comment: this did not work

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly getting a 403 error. The error is caused because ? is a banned file/directory name character on Windows and Linux. This means when Apache attempts to find a file or directory named "/document/root/index.php?blah" (after decoding) and it causes a 403 error. This is before the .htaccess files are read so you cannot use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file to override this 403 error or an ErrorDocument defined in the .htaccess file to catch this error.

**The only way to catch %3f is to use mod_rewrite or an ErrorDocument in a "VirtualHost"** e.g. in httpd-vhosts.conf (or the main server configuration if there aren't any "Virtualhost"s e.g. in httpd.conf).

Comment: “? is a banned file/directory name character on Linux” ??? As if one stupid answer wasn't enough, [you wrote two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35156732/2698019).